# How to restrict specific number of threads to synchronized block in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not able to figure out this question. In a multi threaded environment - exactly 3 threads should be able to execute the synchronized block and rest should wait ?

What I understand is when we use synchronization or monitor one thread will wait until the other thread finishes its execution in side synchronized block or method. To achieve multiple thread  to enter inside synchronized block or method we need to use wait(), notify(), notifyAll() i.e. inter thread communication, where wait() method when called on certain object it will takes its lock and give chances to other waiting threads.

So, I am wondering how to do the above question. I am not sure if I have put my question in right way. If its possible do we need to use java concurrent util package or can it be done in basic(core) thread functionality.

Comment: You're probably looking for a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: Why would you do this?  This sounds like a problem which should be solved another way.

Comment: I was asked this question by one of my friend. Now I got the concept of semaphore.

Answer (score 6):

Use a semaphore with three permits:

> Semaphores are often used to restrict the number of threads that can
>   access some (physical or logical) resource.

Answer (score 3):

Using a semaphore would probably be the best solution to your problem, but it doesn't hurt to try your own solution, even though it's just for the sake of experimenting and maybe learning something new.

Here is a quick example of a lock implementation using `LinkedBlockingQueue`. This lock will only allow a certain number of threads to access the block of code between `getKey()` and `returnKey()`:

```
public class Lock {

    private int keys;

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> q;

    public Lock(int keys) throws InterruptedException {
        q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        while (q.size() != keys)
            q.put(0);
    }

    public void getKey() throws InterruptedException {
        q.take();
    }

    public void returnKey() throws InterruptedException {
        q.put(0);
    }

    static Lock lck;
    public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException {

        lck = new Lock(3);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    lck.getKey();
                    Lock.test();
                    lck.returnKey();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        for (int t = 0; t < 10; t ++) 
            new Thread(r).start();
    }

    public static void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("I am " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```